# Rotate canvas arc on its centre

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have a canvas with an arc and some labels inside it.

Here is the fiddle link - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2EYw/790/) and below is the code:

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    x = canvas.width / 2,
    y = canvas.height / 2,
    radius = 100;

ctx.lineWidth = 2;

var numberofArcs = 10,
    sengmentWidth = 1.5 * Math.PI / numberofArcs,
    pieAngle = 1.5 * Math.PI / numberofArcs;

console.log(pieAngle);

var labeltext = '',
    font = 16,
    hightlight = 1;

drawSegments(radius, font, hightlight);

ctx.translate(x, y);
ctx.rotate(135 * Math.PI);
ctx.translate(-x, -y);

function drawSegments(radius, font, highlight) {
    var offset = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < numberofArcs; i++) {
        (i<=8) ? offset = 3 : offset = 8;
        
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);

        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, i * pieAngle, (i + 1) * pieAngle);

        var hueValue = i * 15;

        ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + hueValue + ',70%, 60%)';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#f3f5f6';
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);
        ctx.arc(x, y, radius - 10, i * pieAngle, (i + 1) * pieAngle);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#f3f5f6';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.lineWidth = 0;
        labeltext = i + 1;
        ctx.font = '16px bold white';

        var width = ctx.measureText(labeltext).width;
        ctx.fillStyle = '#CCC';

        if ((i + 1) == highlight) {
            ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';

            console.log(offset);

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x + offset +(radius + 30) * Math.cos(i * pieAngle + ((i + 1) * pieAngle - i * pieAngle) / 2), y + (radius + 30) * Math.sin(i * pieAngle + ((i + 1) * pieAngle - i * pieAngle) / 2));
            ctx.arc(x + offset + (radius + 30) * Math.cos(i * pieAngle + ((i + 1) * pieAngle - i * pieAngle) / 2), y + (radius + 30) * Math.sin(i * pieAngle + ((i + 1) * pieAngle - i * pieAngle) / 2), 10, 0,  2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
            ctx.fill();

            ctx.fillStyle = "#000";

            ctx.fillText(labeltext, x + (radius + 30) * Math.cos(i * pieAngle + ((i + 1) * pieAngle - i * pieAngle) / 2), y + (radius + 30) * Math.sin(i * pieAngle + ((i + 1) * pieAngle - i * pieAngle) / 2));
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.fillText(labeltext, x + (radius + 30) * Math.cos(i * pieAngle + ((i + 1) * pieAngle - i * pieAngle) / 2), y + (radius + 30) * Math.sin(i * pieAngle + ((i + 1) * pieAngle - i * pieAngle) / 2));
        }
    }
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

What I want to achieve is rotate the whole arc along with labels by 135 degrees.
I tried this code but it did not work :

```
ctx.translate(x, y);
ctx.rotate(135 * Math.PI/180);
ctx.translate(-x, -y);
```

Where x and y are canvas center points.
Any help would be appreciated.
PS: I'm new to canvas !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is symetrical as you rotate it is easy to just add to the angle we draw segments at by the amount we want to rotate the circle by.

There was a lot of code doing nothing so have cut you code down to be a little more manageable.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2;
const radius = 100;
const numberofArcs = 10;
const sengmentWidth = 1.5 * Math.PI / numberofArcs;
const pieAngle = 1.5 * Math.PI / numberofArcs;
const spacePixels = 4;
const spaceRadians = spacePixels / radius;
const fontHeight = 16;
const textOffset = 30;
var hightlight = 1;
var angle = 135 * (Math.PI / 180);

drawSegments(x, y, radius, hightlight, angle);


function drawSegments(x, y, radius, highlight, angle) {
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.font = fontHeight + 'px bold white';
    // move center to x,y pos
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x,y);
    x = y = 0;
    // draw the light gray pie and border
    var offset = 0;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.arc(0,0,radius + spacePixels, angle, angle + numberofArcs * pieAngle);
    ctx.lineTo(0,0); // or could use closePath
    ctx.fillStyle = '#f3f5f6';
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#e3e5e6';
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    
    // for each segment draw coloured arc and text
    for (var i = 0; i < numberofArcs; i++) {
        var pA = pieAngle * i; // angle of start of pie pA;
        var tDir  = (i + 0.5) * pieAngle;  // angle of text
        pA += angle;  // add the rotated angle
        tDir += angle;
        var dist = radius + textOffset; // text distance from center
        var sR = spaceRadians; // the spacnig between segments
        
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#d3d5d6';  // for adding outline to coloured arcs
        ctx.lineWidth = 4;  // outline width is half this amount
        ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + (i*15) + ',70%, 60%)';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, pA + sR, pA + pieAngle -sR);  // outside CW
        ctx.arc(x, y, radius - 10,pA + pieAngle -sR, pA + sR,true);  // then inside CCW
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();
        if ((i + 1) === highlight) {
            
            ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(dist * Math.cos(tDir), dist  * Math.sin(tDir), 10, 0,  2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.fill();
        }
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillText(""+(i + 1), Math.cos(tDir) * dist, Math.sin(tDir) * dist); 

    }
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```